# Conjugates iff conjugates over $\mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, matrices, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, almost simple linear algebraic group defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $g, g'\in G(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be conjugates by an element of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$. Does it follow that they are conjugates by an element of $G(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$?

(This is true if $G$ is classical (namely, $\mathrm{SL}_n$, $\mathrm{SO}_n$, $\mathrm{Sp}_n$), by a result by Freudenthal (1951), Elementarteilertheorie...)

Answer (score 12):

There is a subtlety in the question as to how we may embed $G$ into $GL_n$, i.e. which faithful representations of $G$ we may choose. If the answer is "any", the answer is negative for trivial reasons. If the answer is "only irreducible representations" or even "only the `standard' representation of the group" the answer is negative for somewhat less trivial reasons.

If $g$ and $g'$ are involutions (in characteristic not 2) then they are conjugate in $GL_n$ if and only if they have the same trace. So all you need for a counterexample is an almost simple algebraic group with two non-conjugate involutions, say $SL_4$ with the involutions with $-1$-eigenspaces of dimension $2$ and $4$, and two faithful representations where we have the same trace. These involutions have trace $0$ and $-4$ on the standard representation or $-2$ and $6$ on  $\wedge^2$, so on the direct sum of $\wedge^2$ and two copies of the standard representation, both involutions have trace $-2$ and thus are conjugate.

Probably there are lots of examples with irreducible representations but a simple one arises from the spin group. If I calculated right, any element of $\operatorname{Spin}_{2n+1}$ whose image in $SO_{2n+1}$ is an involution with number of $-1$ eigenvalues a positive multiple of $4$ is, in the standard spin representation, an involution with trace zero, so all these involutions are conjugate in $GL_{2^n}$, but for $n\geq 4$ there are at least two such involutions not conjugate in $\operatorname{Spin}_{2n+1}$ (since they are not conjugate in $SO_{2n+1}$).

My calculations: An element of $SO_{2n+1}$ with eigenvalues $a_1,\dots, a_n, a_1^{-1},\dots, a_n^{-1},1$ lifts to an element of the spin group with eigenvalues all numbers obtained by dividing $\sqrt{a_1\dots a_n}$ by some subset of the $a_1,\dots, a_n$. If $a_1,\dots, a_n$ are all $\pm 1$ with the number of $-1$s positive and even, then $\sqrt{a_1\dots a_n}=1$ and half the eigenvalues are $+1$ and half are $-1$.

Comment: Say $K$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, and $G$ is a simple algebraic group over $K$. [Steinberg](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(78)90226-0) proved that if $p = 0$ or $p$ is large enough, then $g, g' \in G$ are $G$-conjugate if and only if $f(g), f(g')$ are $GL(V)$-conjugate for every rational irreducible representation $f: G \rightarrow GL(V)$. He also conjectured that this would be true in general, but there are counterexamples: [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00031-019-09538-3).

Comment: That's very nice!